# Javascript copy nested arrays of objects with functions

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, copy

Hi
I want to copy array of objects in javascript with functions.

I have object like this

```
var User = function() {
    this.name = '';
    var surname = '';

    function f() {
        //some function here
    }

    this.sayHello = function() {
        console.log( 'Hello ' + this.name + ' ' + surname )
    }
}

var arr = [];
arr.push([ new User(), new User()]);
arr.push([ new User(), new User()]);
```

As you see, I have object with some private and public properties declared this and war and private and public functions.

Is there any method to copy this array? 
I user this method

```
function copy( arr ) {
    var c = [];
    for( var i = 0; i < arr.length; i ++ ) {
        c.push(arr[i].concat([]));
    }
}
```

In this method, when I changed some property of some object, property changes for copied object too.

```
var arr2 = copy(arr)
arr[0][0].name = 'name';
console.log(arr2[0][0].name) // prints 'name'
```

Is there method to copy nested array of objects with functions ? 
Than you.

Comment: A nice solution that should work for all cases is [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/122190/3399432).

Comment: There isn't one built-in. And, creating it isn't necessarily simple while keeping prototype chains in place. [Most elegant way to clone a JavaScript object](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/728360/most-elegant-way-to-clone-a-javascript-object)

Comment: @UtsavShah there really isn't a deep-copy solution that will work for *all* cases; it's a non-trivial problem. However that link you provided is probably the best place to start :)

Comment: You're right @Pointy

Comment: thank you all. but I have one more question . Can I copy object with functions ?

Comment: @Gor well you can't make a copy of a function, but you don't have to - functions are immutable. Thus, your deep-copy operation only needs to worry about object properties that are array or (non-function) object references. References to functions can just be copied.